# Cómo guardar caracteres en español e inglés en Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

Tengo problemas para guardar caracteres en español en Postgres.

Por ejemplo  á, é, í,ó,ú, and ä, ü, ñ, Ñ.

Alguna idea como solucionar esto?

Ademas me gustaria no tener porblema con caracteres tipico de inglés (que creo no tiene caracteres especiales). Es decir que no haya problemas con español e ingles.

## Actualización:

Parece que la BDatos esta en UTF-8, yo utilice este comando al crearla:

`DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS lawyers_db; 
CREATE DATABASE lawyers_db WITH ENCODING='UTF8';`

Me sale este error: `ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0x81 in encoding "WIN
1252" has no equivalent in encoding "UTF8"`

## Resuelto:

Yo estaba intentando ejecutar el comando desde windows git bash y nada funciono, entonces intente ejecutar mi sql script en pgAdmin III como sugirió @Luiggi y ahi si sirvio el comando e ingreso los caracteres especiales como Ññóá etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando crees la base de datos, asegúrate de que tenga codificación UTF8.

Aquí un ejemplo:

```
CREATE DATABASE miBaseDeDatos
WITH ENCODING = 'UTF8';
```

Si tu base de datos ya existe y quieres agregarle este soporte, deberás seguir la recomendación de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5090923/1065197), traducida:

> 1. Respaldar tu base de datos
> 2. Eliminar la base de datos
> 3. Crear una nueva base de datos con la codificación diferente
> 4. Levantar el respaldo de tu base de datos en esta base de datos

Para ver la codificación actual de tu base de datos, utiliza el siguiente comando desde un terminal:

```
psql nombre_de_tu_bd -c 'SHOW SERVER_ENCODING'
```

Comment: Luiggi puedes leer mi actualizacion por favor.

Comment: @Jeka respuesta actualizada. Te recomiendo verificar la codificación de tu base de datos. Según entiendo el error, tu codificación no es UTF8. Para estar más seguros, convendría que revises la codificación específica de la base de datos con la que trabajas.

Comment: @Jeka parece que tu cliente utiliza codificación WIN1252. Cambia la codificación que utilizas en el cliente utilizando `SET client_encoding = 'UTF8'` y lulego vuelve a crear la base de datos.

Comment: `SET client_encoding = 'UTF8'` es en la linea de comando de windows? o en la de postgres?

Comment: @Jeka eso lo ejecutas en tu cliente. Por ejemplo, si estás utilizando una ventana de pgAdmin III para crear la base de datos, ejecutas el `SET client_encoding` allí. Si estás utilizando el cliente desde línea de comandos, entonces allí ejecutas la sentencia. Luego de eso, ejecuta tu sentencia para crear la base de datos.

Comment: gracias Luiggi intente todo lo que me dijiste, lo unico que sirvio fue correr mi sql script desde pgAdmin 3, Estaba corriendolo desde Gitbash en windows a lo mejor ahi estaba el problema. Pero corriendolo desde pgAdmin III se soluciono el problema creo que mejor me acostumbro a ese GUI. Vos sabés si pgAdmin sirve en un VPS de ubunut como digital ocean?

Comment: @Jeka creo que mientras tengas acceso a un entorno visual, puedes utilizar pgAdmin III sin problemas. Yo lo uso en Windows, Ubuntu y Mac sin problemas.

Answer (score 2):

yo te recomiendo que la codificación que ocupes es UTF8, tanto para la base de datos, como para los documentos html, php, javascript, etc.

Aquí te dejo un poco de documentación sobre [Soporte de Codificación](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/multibyte.html)

---

**EDICIÓN POR CONTINUIDAD DE COMENTARIO**

Bien puedes entonces crear la base de datos basandote en la template

`CREATE DATABASE tabla ENCODING 'UTF8' TEMPLATE template0;`

[Extraído desde la documentación oficial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createdatabase.html)

Comment: Yo utilice `DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS lawyers_db;
CREATE DATABASE lawyers_db WITH  ENCODING='UTF8';` cuando cree la base de datos y me sale este error:  `ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0x81 in encoding "WIN
1252" has no equivalent in encoding "UTF8"`

Comment: Actualizado @Jeka

Answer (score -1):

Esto me funciona

```
CREATE DATABASE db_authorization_authentication
   WITH OWNER = postgres
   ENCODING = 'UTF8'
   TABLESPACE = pg_default
   LC_COLLATE = 'Spanish_Argentina.1252'
   LC_CTYPE = 'Spanish_Argentina.1252'
   CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

Comment: Hola Edgardo, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Esta respuesta es de baja calidad. Sigue [answer] para mejorarla con explicaciones.  Un saludo.

Comment: El voto negativo que recibiste seguramente es porque pusiste únicamente el código, deberías de agregar al menos una razón de porque te funciona en mi opinión.